# Google Workspace Add-On Hide or Edit App Bar Card

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I developed an add-on for google workspace.
I followed the [official guide](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/card-interfaces) for sidebar development.

Searching in the `developers.google.com` portal and in the Google [Figma UI StyleGuide](https://www.figma.com/community/file/848275628252039675) provided for the documentation of the add-on, I can't find how to change or hide the **Add on top bar** (not Header Card).

As you can see from the first photo attached (my add-on) I have defined the "**Card Header**", but it still remains the "add-on" Header Bar"([ref](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/cards)) that I would like to change or remove, like those of Google (attached photo) or other add-ons on the store.

Someone knows to modify it or has a reference where he explains how to do it?

Thank you so much!

[image: myAddOn] [image: OthersAddOn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only customization that is available for the add-on header are the displayed name and the background color (fields `name` and `layoutProperties` in [Common](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/manifest/addons#common) field, in your [manifest](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests)).

[image]

#### Feature request:

If you'd like this functionality to be implemented, I'd suggest you to file a feature request on Issue Tracker, using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).