# How to localize the Gmail add-on header name in the manifest file (appscript.json)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing a Gmail add-on with multi language support. I need to localized the addon's header name. Header name is presented in the manifest file. I was not able to figure out a way to localized the addon's header name to user's language. Is it possible to localizes the header name? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

[image: Add-on header]

This is how my manifest looks like,

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://abcd.com/"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Add-on name",
    "logoUrl": "https://abcd.com/gmail/assets/logo_32x32.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddon"
      }
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4d90fe",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://abcd.com/"
    ],
    "useLocaleFromApp": true
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example situation that will help us to understand the service that you are trying to provide for your clients.

Comment: I think you'd like to automatically have the add-on detect what your user's preferred language is and translate the header based on what it gets. `Is it possible to localizes the header name?` Try looking at the method [`getActiveUserLocale()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale\(\)) and see if that'll help. Though I think it's safer to create a UI asking the user what their preferred language is since there are people who still prefer English.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thank you very much for reaching out. My Gmail add-on provides multi language support. As an example, if the user’s language is French when user run the add-on user can see the add-on content with the French. But the issue is I can’t find a way to access add-on header name from code and change according to user locale or localized using manifest.

Comment: Hi @Saddles, thank you very much for reaching out. I previously used
[getActiveUserLocale()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale())
method to access the user locale. 
There was some issues with that method

Comment: So, currently I am using `commonEventObject.userLocale` and display the translated content. But from the code I can't find a way to access the add-on header name and change it according to the user locale. add-on header name is defined in the manifest file and if I change the add-on name from manifest it appears fine in add-on header, but I also can't find a way to localize that name from manifest also. @Saddles

Comment: It seems that this can be considered a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new). I found this [Stack Oveflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579452) answered by [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011), stating that `the only customization that is available for the add-on header are the displayed name and the background color` implying that the display name can be changed in the manifest but having it translated even with a function is unavailable.